# $result = call_user_func_array($callable, $arguments); where is my wrong it isn't working

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHa1y.png)

```
/**
     * Call the underlying filesystem method.
     *
     * @param string $method
     * @param array  $arguments
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function callFilesystemMethod($method, array $arguments)
    {
        $callable = 'parent::'.$method;
        $result = call_user_func_array($callable, $arguments);

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome. Please show the error text, not an image of it. Also make sure to format your post correctly (edit your question). Thanks.

Comment: An exception occurred: [ErrorException] [E_WARNING] Undefined array key "legacyExists" in src\XF\App.php on line 1732

XF::handlePhpError() in src/XF/App.php at line 1732
XF\App->setup() in src/XF/Pub/App.php at line 89
XF\Pub\App->setup() in src/XF.php at line 364
XF::setupApp() in src/XF.php at line 387
XF::runApp() in index.php at line 20
bekle
if ($config['legacyExists'])
            {
2. parent::setup($options);
3.
$app->setup($setupOptions);
4.
$app = self::setupApp($appClass);
5.
\XF::runApp('XF\Pub\App');

Comment: Please edit your question rather than providing updates in the comments.